# How to use std::expected in conjunction with std::transform?

Tags: c++, exception, std-expected

I have a flatbuffer. This flatbuffer has a `vector<T>` that I want to transform using `std::transform` into a `std::vector<U>`.

It is possible that `T` can contain values that are not valid - because they are a plain integer converted to an enum. In this case, I want to abort the whole transform process.

Currently I throw an exception within the lambda of `std::transform` and catch it in the function that calls the transform function.

```cpp
std::transform(deserialized_level.rooms.cbegin(), deserialized_level.rooms.cend(), constant_level_data.rooms.begin(),
    [&out_progress, &deserialized_rooms, &deserialized_level](const std::unique_ptr<room_t>& deserialized_room) {
        auto r = room_info{};
        r.position = int3(deserialized_room->position->x, deserialized_room->position->y, deserialized_room->position->z);
        r.sector_width = (unsigned char)(deserialized_room->sector_count_x);
        r.sector_length = (unsigned char)(deserialized_room->sector_count_z);
        auto sector_dimension = sector_size::normal;
        switch(deserialized_room->square_size) {
            case 256:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::smallest;
                break;
            case 512:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::smaller;
                break;
            case 1024:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::normal;
                break;
            case 2048:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::large;
                break;
            case 4096:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::very_large;
                break;
            case 8192:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::huge;
                break;
            case 16384:
                sector_dimension = sector_size::gigantic;
                break;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("Unknown sector size detected!" + std::to_string(deserialized_room->square_size));
        }
        //...//
        return r;
});
```

How would I model this with `std::expected`? A `std::vector<std::expected<T,E>>` seems kinda silly.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  Could even parallelise it, while you're at it.

Comment: Do you wish to continue the transform after the first error or should it break then?

Comment: `In this case, I want to abort the whole transform process.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transformation is to be aborted at the first unexpected value, an exception in the lambda is the right choice. It is the only way to cancel a `std::transform`.

What you want as a result is probably `std::expected<std::vector<U>, std::string>`. To do this, you put the `std::transform` call into a function that returns a corresponding `std::expected`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <expected>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct room { int size; };
struct room_info { std::string category;};

std::expected<std::vector<room_info>, std::string>
info_of(std::vector<room> const& rooms) try {
    std::vector<room_info> infos;
    infos.reserve(rooms.size());
    std::ranges::transform(rooms, std::back_inserter(infos),
        [](room const& r) -> room_info{
            using namespace std::literals;
            switch(r.size) {
                case 256:
                    return {"smallest"s};
                case 1024:
                    return {"normal"s};
                case 4096:
                    return {"very_large"s};
                case 16384:
                    return {"gigantic"s};
                default:
                    throw "invalid room size"s;
            }
        });
    return infos;
} catch (std::string error) {
    return std::unexpected(std::move(error));
}
```

Note that you can still throw other exceptions normally. The `std::expected` here only receives `throw`'s with `std::string`.

You can use it like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void print(std::expected<std::vector<room_info>, std::string> const& info) {
    if(info) {
        auto const& list = info.value();
        std::cout << "[";
        if(!list.empty()) {
            std::cout << list[0].category;
            for(std::size_t i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                std::cout << ", " << list[i].category;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "]\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << info.error() << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    print(info_of({{256}, {16384}, {1024}}));
    print(info_of({{256}, {16385}, {1024}}));
}
```

```
[smallest, gigantic, normal]
invalid room size
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with any of this per-se, but wouldn't it make sense to allow the exception to propagate up to the point where you want to handle it?

Comment: @PaulSanders No, you can't say that in general. It depends on how you want to react to the respective problem. Just this example shows very nicely that exceptions and std::expected are orthogonal techniques that can even be used together. Parsing errors occur frequently and are therefore rather processed in the normal control flow. However, the lambda could also throw a bad_alloc. This rarely happens and is therefore rather handled completely via exceptions.

Comment: That argument lacks substance.  `std::bad_alloc`, in particular, tends to be terminal.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, of course `bad_alloc` is a very bad example. Just assume any other exception. Had named `bad_alloc` only because it is the only other thing that could occur in the above code. But that is simply due to the simplicity of the minimal example. A more complicated transform lambda code may throw other exceptions ;-)